# discord.py not installing with pip need visual c++

Tags: python, pip, installation

I am currently trying to pip install Discord.py to make a discord bot.
unfortunatly I am getting an erorr that states, that microsoft visual c++ needs to be installed.
Do I really have to do this?

Full error:

error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual c++
 Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0` in order for discord.py to function.
There isn't a way to work around that error.